# Targum to Ex. 32:27

Tags: words, parashat-ki-tisa, targumin

Why do the *targumim* to *Sh'mos* 32:27 ("וְהִרְגוּ אִישׁ אֶת אָחִיו וְאִישׁ אֶת רֵעֵהוּ וְאִישׁ אֶת קְרֹבוֹ") use *g'var* twice and then *enash*?

For example, *[Onkelos](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.32.27?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Onkelos_Exodus.32.27&lang2=bi)*:

> וקטולו גבר ית אחוהי וגבר ית חבריה ואנש ית קריביה

Comment: You mean _g'var_ thrice then _enash_.

Comment: Seems to not be the only place where we have this inconsistency; other examples include Ex. 10:23 and Num. 26:64-65. (This is aside from the places where the Torah uses the words אדם or נפש, both of which Onkelos consistently translates as אנש.)

Comment: @R'WAF, I meant the last two, which are parallel (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_%28rhetoric%29). @R'Alex, I see only _enash_ in Ex. 10:23, no _g'var_; and neither it nor Num. 26:64–65 has the parallel structure I was thinking of.

Comment: ...but, yes, the question is a good one IMO even without the parallel structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [pasuk](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/u/up0209.htm) in question:
לב,כז וַיֹּאמֶר לָהֶם, כֹּה-אָמַר יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל, שִׂימוּ אִישׁ-חַרְבּוֹ, עַל-יְרֵכוֹ; עִבְרוּ וָשׁוּבוּ מִשַּׁעַר לָשַׁעַר, בַּמַּחֲנֶה, וְהִרְגוּ אִישׁ-אֶת-אָחִיו וְאִישׁ אֶת-רֵעֵהוּ, וְאִישׁ אֶת-קְרֹבוֹ.

and the Targum:
וַאֲמַר לְהוֹן, כִּדְנָן אֲמַר יְיָ אֱלָהָא דְּיִשְׂרָאֵל, שַׁוּוֹ גְּבַר חַרְבֵּיהּ, עַל יִרְכֵּיהּ; עֵיבַרוּ וְתוּבוּ מִתְּרַע לִתְרַע, בְּמַשְׁרִיתָא, וּקְטוּלוּ גְּבַר יָת אֲחוּהִי וּגְבַר יָת חַבְרֵיהּ, **וַאֲנָשׁ** יָת קָרִיבֵיהּ.

I don't have a ready answer to this variance. However, I can point out that the [Samaritan Targum](http://books.google.com/books?id=N0cQAAAAYAAJ&dq=%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8&pg=PA105#v=onepage&q&f=false) lacks this difference, and has גבר for each. [Targum Pseudo-Yonatan](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39657&st=&pgnum=179) has the divergence. Except that [this Tg Pseudo-Yonatan](http://www.peshitta.org/pdf/ot/Exodus.pdf) also has the divergence, or maybe not. They apparently have both nuschaot, and someone selects אנש as the correct one.[image: a Trilinear Targum Yonasan]

Similarly, for Onkelos, I am not entirely convinced that אנש is the correct text. If we look at [dfus Savyonita](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21711&st=&pgnum=285), from 1557, we find the following in Onkelos:[image: dfus Savyonita from 1557.].

I underlined וגבר in red. So too in this [Chumash](http://jnul.huji.ac.il/dl/books/djvu/1158964/index.djvu?djvuopts&thumbnails=yes&zoom=page&page=91), from Bologna in 1482.

[image: Chumash from Bolgna in 1482.]

So we really should investigate as best we can manuscripts of Onkelos to determine that the phenomenon is real, before setting out to explain the phenomenon. Tg Yonatan might have been bleed-over from texts of Onkelos, so I wouldn't take it as such strong evidence.

(Targum Neofiti has גבר while Peshitta has אנש - see Argon's comment.)

Off the cuff, my inclination is that אנש is used as a translation of person, while גבר is used as a translation of male person. I can see how each would fit well in context. We are saying that each and every person should take X action, so I would expect אנש. But on the other hand, the people involved are warriors, and thus are surely males, so I can understand גבר as a replacement. My **inclination** is that Onkelos selected only one of these, but some text emended all of these, and someone wrote אנש as a marginal gloss once, to indicate the general divergence, which was then misinterpreted to mean a replacement of only one of these. I cannot prove it, though, and צריך עיון.

Comment: Thank you!! Checkmark for now; I'll reassign it if someone has a surer answer.

Comment: I would add that Targum Neofiti has: "וקטלו גבר ית אחוי וגבר ית חבריה וגבר ית קריביה" while the Peshitta (in Hebrew characters) has: "וקטולו אנש לאחוהי ואנש לחברה ואנש לקריבה"

Answer (score 5):

The sefer ביאורי אונקלוס [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6773&st=&pgnum=83&hilite=) (posuk 21) writes:

> ידוע שדרכו תמיד שלא לדבר בכפל לשון בכל מקום שאפשר להביא מלה אחרת מפני יופי הלשון
>
> It is well known that it is the way of Onkelos not to use the same word twice in the same posuk if it is possible to use a different word (a synonym) for the beautification of the language.